# Swift Replace all special characters

Tags: ios, swift, regex, string

How can I replace all accented characters in a string with standard ASCII characters?

***Examples***

```
from: cartões
to:   cartoes
```

```
from: notificações
to:   notificacoes
```

Comment: Why do you need this? If your intent is to search a string what you need is `localizedStandardContains` which is case and diacritic insensitive as well as locale-aware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift has built in support for stripping diacritics/annotations from strings.  This is primarily to support easy searching and comparisons but will solve your problem too.  The API is

```
func folding( options: String.CompareOptions = [],
    locale: Locale?) -> String
```

If you will be using it regularly, the easiest way would be to create an extension on String with the required parameters preset:

```
extension String {
  func cleaned() -> Self {
    return self.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
  }
}
```

which would let you do `"notificações".cleaned()` to return `notificacoes`

Comment: `Swift has built in support` This is not true. There is no "built-in" method AFAIK.  `folding` as well as `applyingTransform` methods require you to import `Foundation`.

Comment: Slightly pedantic, but technically accurate :)